# Including a flash file(.swf) in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have include a flash file on my php file and this file is viewed properly in computer browser. But when i open page in mobile browser then it doesn't show this flash(.swf) file.

```
<embed width="400" height="50" src="adv.swf">
```

Comment: Perhaps your mobile browser doesn't support flash

Comment: No any mobile browser not show @MarkBaker

Comment: Try this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/embedding-flash/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using the object approach.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="adv.swf" width="400" height="50"> 
  <param name="movie" value="adv.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
</object>
```

On the other hand you can also go for [google swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) or you can convert the `swf` file to a `video` format since its more widely supported on the mobile devices.